# Troubleshooting the network connection on a Windows 10 PC in LAN

Tags: network-programming, ethernet, lan, smb, file-sharing

I have a small LAN and one of the PCs (Windows 10) started to behave weird after a Windows update.

Here it how it behaves:

- This PC can be seen on the network. If I ping it from other computers, it works.
- The shared folders on this PC can be accessed by other computers correctly.
- But programs on this PC that must respond to requests made by programs installed on other devices with access this PC in either ethernet or wifi by [IP:Port#] , now don't work anymore.
  These programs used to work properly before and I think the change in behavior happened after a Windows update.

An example of such program is "Winpopup LAN Messenger"
( https://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Chat/LAN-Messaging-Clients/Winpopup-LAN-Messenger.shtml )

I checked the network advanced sharing settings and it's set like before (Turn on network discovery, Turn on file and printer sharing).

I disabled the firewall / windows defender.

With netstat -an command in cmd prompt I can see that those programs are listening to the UDP ports that they are supposed to listen to, however they don't respond to incoming requests from other machines.

I am really puzzled about this weird new behavior.

Any hints would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could figure it out.  All the problems came from the firewall settings.

In Windows Defender Firewall > Allow an app or feature > check both 'Private' and 'Public' for all instances of WinPopup LAN Messenger > click OK
Also, the port used is 1152 and protocol UDP. This port must be opened (also in firewall).

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you did regarding the firewall settings (eg. what you changed or modified) that made the problem go away?

Comment: Great, can you now incorporate that into your answer?

Comment: Just did that...